# Abrir página diretamente em um determinado slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma página que é inteiramente um slide, apenas com o menu ao lado. Gostaria de saber como faço para abrir essa página diretamente em um determinado slide. Já tentei pelo método comum e mais conhecido, acrescentando um ID a cada item do slide, que é uma lista (li) e depois chamo a página passando o link da mesma + o id do slide que quero abrir. Porém nada acontece e sempre abre no primeiro item do slide. Se alguém tiver ideias seria de grande ajuda. Obrigado.

```
<li id="item1">
```

Chamando o item:

```
<a href="pagina.html#item1">
```

Comment: Qual lib você está usando? Você precisa verificar a API da sua lib para realizar tal ação. Quando utilizamos o [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), podemos usar `initialSlide: 2`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [jQuery](http://jquery.com), detectando a [distancia](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) do topo da página para a `li`, e depois fazendo a pagina rolar até esse ponto.

Veja esse exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/diancabral/t9fx77b5/